# Django 1.11 - Order Queryset by Postgresql xmin column

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, django-1.11

My objective is to order a queryset by last modified. I searched for a solution and found the "xmin" attribute ([1](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/D960CB61B694CF459DCFB4B0128514C2031AB58B%40exadv11.host.magwien.gv.at)). I couldn't find how to access this "pseudo" column, leading me to think about "annotate" each xmin from a queryset using raw SQL, since the following SQL works:

```
SELECT xmin, * FROM media ORDER BY xmin::text::bigint;
```

My tries were the following three :

- Apply raw SQL to a queryset
  I know am doing something wrong, since the SQL applies to the whole table, not only for the current queryset:

  ```
  mediaQS = Media.objects.filter(id__in=mediaIDList)
  for media in mediaQS.annotate(xmin=RawSQL("SELECT xmin FROM media ;")):
       print "media.xmin",media.xmin`
  ```

Which raises TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

- My second and third tries are based on [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29743) (Django 2.1)

  ```
  for media in mediaQS.extra(select={'my_xmin': 'xmin'}):
      print "media.my_xmin",media.my_xmin
  ```

Which gives

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "xmin" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (xmin) AS "my_xmin", "media"."id", "media"."path_id",...
            ^
HINT:  There is a column named "xmin" in table "media", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

and

```
    from django.db.models import Expression    
    class XMin(Expression): 
        output_field = models.PositiveIntegerField()

        def as_postgresql(self, compiler, connection):
            return 'xmin', ()

    for media in mediaQS.annotate(my_xmin=XMin()):
         print "media.my_xmin",media.my_xmin
```

Which gives a similar error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "xmin" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."path" AS "media_path", T4."path" AS "thumbnail", xmin AS "m...
                                                         ^
HINT:  There is a column named "xmin" in table "media", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

If someone can help with a solution for Django 1.11, I appreciate.

Comment: In your second and third solutions, does it work if you access `media.my_xmin`?

Comment: I forgot to tell the output. I'll edit. They both raise django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "xmin" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (xmin) AS "my_xmin", "media"."id", "media"."path_id",...
                ^
HINT:  There is a column named "xmin" in table "media", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

Comment: Curious. I can't reproduce this error on either Python 2 or Python 3. If I run `media.my_xmin`, it works just fine. What version of PostgreSQL are you on?

Comment: Also, the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-system-columns.html) say that "In a long-lived database it is possible for transaction IDs to wrap around."
This means that it might be a bad idea to use `xmin` depending on the size of your database, because after several billion transactions it will wrap around to 0 and no longer be valid. I recommend adding a `last_modified` field on the Django side instead (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) for details).

Comment: Postgresql 9.6.10. I was already thinking about this option of modifying my model to having this last_modified field. I was avoiding messing with models and migrations but I agree I should do this. But, I am still curious about the solution, even it is not the ideal. Anyway, thanks for the support.